# Add functions in Usecase diagram

Tags: use-case

I'm drawing Use case diagram for my Final year project. I have some activities such as type letters,type symbols, type numbers. Should I put them as one case or three separate cases?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UML use cases offer generalization as a relationship type. You can show here only the general "type braille characters" and in another diagram, you might show how that use case has several subtypes.

However, keep it simple. Only do that kind of detailed decomposition if it brings added value to your reader.